# STL ref and cref functions

Tags: c++, stl

Why in C++ presented two functions with different names `ref` and `cref`? Why not the only overloaded `ref` function? Are there some important semantic reasons?

Comment: It is similar to `begin`/`cbegin`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because sometimes you want to wrap a `const` reference to a non-`const` object. In such cases, `std::cref` allows you to write

```
std::cref(x)
```

instead of

```
std::ref(static_cast<const T&>(x))
```

(where `T` is of course the type of `x`).

Comment: Therefore I can use exclusively `ref` function in "generic" code, isn't  it? Is `ref` for `const` argument a viable overloading anyways?

Comment: @Orient: I think typically `std::ref`/`std::cref` is used a lot more on the other side of the argument deduction, namely on the call site. Your function  should specialize on a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` and take it from there, generically.